# Read empty string ENV var to HOCON conf but getting weird double quoted empty string

Tags: kotlin, ktor, hocon

I have tried to read empty string env var to HOCON conf but getting weird `""""` when I read it. Tried to read the official doc and tried different variations such as not setting env var at all but could not come to solution.

I am setting env var in `.env` file as

`export SUPPORTED_VALUES=""`

and [HOCON](https://github.com/lightbend/config/blob/main/HOCON.md) configuration as given below

```
{
  feature:
    supported-values: ${?SUPPORTED_VALUES}
}
```

when I read this from Ktor HOCON parser, it reads as `""""` instead of `""`. I tried by giving no value to env var but then it is read as `"null"`

```
    private val supportedValues = appConfig.property("feature.supported-values").getString()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the environment variable contains the literal value `""` ( you can check it out by calling `System.getenv()["SUPPORTED_VALUES"]`). To solve your problem leave the value empty:

```
export SUPPORTED_VALUES=
```

Comment: Then it is taking value as "null". I have a work around for that to filter that, but that looks quite hacky tbh.

Comment: Assuming that your `.env` file is effectively being sourced by the shell before running the code, you could try `unset SUPPORTED_VALUES`, which would then cause the env var to not be incorporated into that config path.